# Multiple dropdowns: what is the proper way to handle them?

Tags: jquery, css, user-interface, drop-down-menu, frameworks

I have to build a little dropdown system that is triggered with clicks. I've managed how to handle the "click out of the div" question (thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152975/how-to-detect-a-click-outside-an-element) previously posted question).

I can hide the *current* dropdown clicking on another dropdown's trigger or clicking outside the *dropdown* itself. So, the problems are these:

1. Click the current dropdown's trigger it's useless; the dropdown doesn't go away while the other things are working properly
2. Clicking *inside* the current dropdown (e.g.: the .divider item), causes the dropdown going away

So, here is the html code (say that I have multiple dropdowns in the header)

```
    ...
    <div id="header" class="navbar">
        <div class="line">
            <a href="#" class="logo">Site Name</a>
            <ul class="nav right">
                <li>
                    <a href="#" class="has-drop">Item 1</span>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Action A</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Action B</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Action C</a></li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li><span>Inline note</span></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="has-drop" href="#">Item 2</a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Action D</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Action E</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Action F</a></li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Action G</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div> <!-- end #header -->
    ...
```

And this is actually the JS code I'm using, in a dedicated file

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $("html").on({
            click: function(e) {
                $(".dropdown-menu.opened").toggleClass("opened");
            }
        });

        $(".nav > li > a").on({
            click: function(e){
                e.stopPropagation();

                $(".dropdown-menu.opened").toggleClass("opened"); // should close each .dropdowns before opening the current one
                $(e.target).siblings(".dropdown-menu").toggleClass("opened");
            }
        });

    });
```

Why do you think the dropdown does not hide when I re-click its trigger? Because inside `$(".nav > li > a").on()` doing practically the same thing?

Also, there is a way to prevent the dropdown hide itself when some of it children are clicked? But maybe this is more related to another question, I don't know.

Last but not least: is this the proper way to do the whole thing, in your opinion?

Thank you all in advance

---

**EDIT**: Thanks to @Beetroot-Beetroot I managed how to solve the problem, so here is the current working code
        $(document).ready(function(){

```
        $("html").on("click", function(e) {
            $(".dropdown-menu.opened").removeClass("opened");
        });

        $(".nav").find("li :first-child").on("click", function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();

            var $thisMenu = $(this).siblings(".dropdown-menu").toggleClass("opened");
            $(".dropdown-menu").not($thisMenu).removeClass("opened");
        });

    });
```

The "secret" was the clever use of .not(), which I now understood more.

I just changed the target (that can `<a>` or `<span>`) into a more generic one. Not sure about the performances in the long term but is certainly a good starting point.

*From*

```
$(".nav").find("a.has-drop").on(...
```

*To*

```
$(".nav").find("li :first-child").on(...
```

Also, here

$(this).closest(".nav").find(".dropdown-menu").not(...
I made it more generic like this
   $(".dropdown-menu").not(...
That's because I want to hide **all** the opened dropdowns. The previous behaviour was considering only one kind of target and only one origin area (e.g.: maybe I need these dropdowns as well in the header and inside some kind of toolbar into the content).

---

**EDIT 2**: @Beetroot-Beetroot helped me again. As him suggested, while I was porting the current code in jsFiddle, suddenly the solution came up quite itself. So now the `$("html").on("click", ...` part looks like this

```
    $("html").on("click", function(e) {

        if ( $(e.target).hasClass("dropdown-menu") || $(e.target).parents(".dropdown-menu").length ) {
            // do nothing, basically
        } else {
            $(".dropdown-menu.opened").removeClass("opened");
        }
    });
```

Basically I just watch if the click from `$("html")` has something to do width the dropdown. If yes, do nothing. If no, then this does mean that I have clicked anywere *but* not where the dropdown was.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It think something like this should do the job :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("html").on('click', function(e) {
        $(".dropdown-menu.opened").removeClass("opened");
    });
    $(".nav").find("a.has-drop").on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        var $thisMenu = $(this).siblings(".dropdown-menu").toggleClass("opened");
        $(this).closest(".nav").find(".dropdown-menu").not($thisMenu).removeClass("opened");
    });
});
```

*untested*

Notes :

- `removeClass()` replaces `toggleClass()` in a couple of places.
- the secret is to toggle `$thisMenu` first, then use `not($thisMenu)` in the following line to ensure that `$thisMenu` remains in whichever state it was toggled to.

Comment: Thank you very much @Beetroot-Beetroot. The key, at the end, was a clever use of .not() in order to avoid the instructions overlapping themselves and be practically identical. Didn't know .not() could be so powerful. Shame on me, eheh.

Comment: Sorry to bothering you, but I still face this problem: clicking inside the dropdown something like .divider element, causes the dropdown itself hide away.
I thought e.stopPropagation(); could stop this kind of problem. Am I wrong?

Comment: L.v.N. - can you set up a working demonstration I can play with. Most people here use [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/).

Comment: Sure! Give me just some minutes then

Comment: Ok! See the "EDIT 2" and there, there is the answer to my own latest question. Thank you again!

Comment: L.v.N., you can probably get the same effect with `$(".nav").on('click', '*', function(e){ e.stopPropagation(); });`. In other words, for all clicks on anything in the nav system, stop propagation.